# Prevenir overflow en input file con nombres de archivo largos

Tags: html, css

He intentado prevenir que se desborde un div a causa de un nombre de archivo muy largo pero no lo logro:

```css
input{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div{
  background: #456;
  padding: 40px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="file4[]" accept=".pdf" type="file">
</div>
```

Los estilos que aplico no funcionan.

Un nombre de archivo ejemplo puede ser:

> archivo+de+prueba+para+test+de+error+con+nombres+de+archivo+muy+largos+overflow de-div.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal lo que quieres es que el nombre del fichero se muestre entero por pantalla sin que se salga del div. Sinceramente, creo que no lo puedes realizar únicamente con CSS, si no que tendrás que utilizar algunos "trucos" para poder realizarlo, y un poco de Javascript. Voy a realizar una imitación del `input` en vez de utilizar el `input` real.

Lo primero que vamos a realizar es crear una `label` que tendrá el atributo `for`, cuyo parámetro será el id de nuestro `input type="file"`. Una vez hecho esto, ocultaremos el input original. De esta manera, el atributo `for` del label, llamará al input para que lance el evento para cargar un fichero, aunque nosotros estaremos pulsando a la etiqueta en vez del input.

Por último crearé un `span` donde almacenaré el texto que contiene mi fichero. Para que no se sobresalga del div y me lo muestre en varias líneas tendré que ponerle una anchura fija tanto al div como al span y utilizar la propiedad `word-wrap: break-word;` de CSS.

La ventaja de utilizar el `label` en vez del `input type="file` para lanzar el evento de cargar los ficheros es que al primero le podemos dar estilos fácilmente y podremos estilizarlo con forma de botón, con forma de input, etc...

**NOTA:** A raíz de tus comentarios, he editado la respuesta con algo de estilos en la `label` para que esta se parezca al `input` original. He puesto uno encima del otro y he quitado el fondo al `div` para que se pueda ver la diferencia. El "input" que está más arriba es el que he personalizado yo y el de abajo sería el original.

Tu ejemplo modificado quedaría así:

```js
var fichero = document.getElementById("fichero");
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");

fichero.onchange = function () {
    texto.innerHTML = fichero.files[0].name;
};
```

```css
#fichero{
  display: none;
}
div{
  /*background: #456;*/
  padding: 40px 10px;
  width: 400px;
}

#boton{
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 2px 7px;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

#texto{
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100%;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="fichero" name="file4[]" accept=".pdf" type="file">
  <label id="boton" for="fichero">Seleccionar archivo</label>
  <span id="texto">Ningún archivo seleccionado</span>
  <input type="file">  
</div>
```

Comment: Me gusta la solución, es como una especie de mascara al input real. Solo le hace falta estilo para emular el original pero me agrada

Comment: @ReneLimon Sí, lo bueno de utilizar la `label` es que puedes darle estilo a ella a tu gusto. Yo me he centrado más en la funcionalidad que en el estilo, aunque si tengo un rato después lo intento adaptar para que parezca el original.

Comment: @ReneLimon He editado la respuesta para darle estilos a la `label` como si fuera el `input` original. El de arriba sería la `label` y el de abajo el `input` original.

Answer (score 1):

Para prevenir el desbordamiento al `input` agregale ancho de caja flexible, es decir, un `width: 100%`, por lo general esto lo soluciona.

Ah y si te esta detectando los estilos, lo que pasa es que no se aplican en esta etiqueta.

```css
input{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
div{
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #456;
  padding: 40px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="file4[]" accept=".pdf" type="file">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo `width: 100%` al **input**:

```
input{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```